# finding pattern between two "CERRADO}" strings using negative look-ahead

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file containing lines like these:

```
CERRADO}165856}TICKET}DESCRIPTION}some random text here\r\n
other random text here}158277747\r\n
CERRADO}165856}TICKET}FR2CODE}more random text also here}1587269339\r\n
```

My ultimate goal is to concatenate those lines not beginnning with "CERRADO}" string with their preceding line. There might be an arbitrary number of lines not beginning with that string on the file. This is the end result:

```
CERRADO}165856}TICKET}DESCRIPTION}some random text here other random text here}158277747\r\n
CERRADO}165856}TICKET}FR2CODE}more random text also here}1587269339\r\n
```

My first attempt was to create a simple regex to match those lines.

```
CERRADO\}.+\r\n(?!CERRADO\})(.+\r\n)+
```

After having that regex right, to create a matching group and replace it getting rid of the \r\n patterns, here is what I have so far:

The proposed regex matches all the lines in the file and not just the wanted ones.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\R(?!CERRADO\})
```

and replace with a space.

The regex matches:

- `\R` - a line break sequence that is...
- `(?!CERRADO\})` - not followed with `CERRADO}`.

Or,

```
^(CERRADO\}.*)\R(?!CERRADO\})
```

and replace with `\1` . This regex matches:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(CERRADO\}.*)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern): `CERRADO}` substring and then the rest of the line
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `(?!CERRADO\})` - not followed with `CERRADO}`.

To make multiple replacements with this one, you will need to hit *Replace All* several times.

[image]